# Why is the site traffic getting choked once I reach 4 Mb/s Network I/O

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php, wordpress

I'm facing this weird issue where I'm unable to tweak the correct value of php-fpm process manager and hence my traffic is getting stuck at a constant `1000 to 1200` concurrent users. (while using a smaller machine I was constantly hitting `2500 to 3000` concurrent users daily).

And I was getting choked at 3000, so I started tweaking and now after hours of racking my brains and monitoring with New Relic, I'm going nowhere. Infact, I've successfully reduced traffic to 1/3rd. Please guide me.

My current php5-fpm conf setting are: /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 300
pm.start_servers = 75
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 150
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

Here's a screensgrab from New Relic
[image]

`php-fpm` takes insane amount of CPU and when it touches near to 100%, traffic chokes and goes down. I'm using `Varnish,` `W3TC` (`object caching` and `DB caching using APC`), `Cloudflare` and even if a few requests can reach php, it shouldn't take so much CPU. Earlier it was not that case before I started tweaking.

Can someone suggest a good setting for my process managers for php-fpm. Please guide me.

Comment: Anything you can do to avoid hitting PHP is good, it's super resource hungry. What percentage of pages are cached vs hitting PHP? How many of your users are logged in vs anonymous? Have you checked the headers coming out of Nginx to ensure Varnish can cache easily? Have you checked image headers coming out of your server to ensure CloudFlare is caching them, can you share a few examples? I don't use Wordpress plugins for caching, virtually everything is in the Nginx page cache so server/php/db are very rarely hit. Can you share your website URL so we can look at the headers?

Comment: @Tim is there a way I can PM you?

Comment: The best idea is to edit your question with all the information requested so others can see it as well - there are a lot of people on this website who are more experienced than me. If you want to contact me you can go into my profile (click my name) and use the contact form on my website, though I charge for one on one professional advice beyond trivial queries. You're meant to be able to start chat threads here but I don't know how, it pops up after there are too many comments usually.

Comment: @Tim I think I found the bottleneck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543601/i-keep-getting-open-failed-2-no-such-file-or-directory-for-old-deleted-file Now my question is should I `disallow: wp-content/uploads` in my `robots.txt` so that the bots don't keep hitting deleted files and php gets respite? Or will it effect anything?

Comment: Images are such are stored in the uploads directory, if you block that your website won't look so good.

Comment: @Tim But it'll only disallow bots, so where will it not look good? Am i missing something?

Comment: Requesting static files doesn't invoke PHP and so uses very little CPU - they're served via Nginx which is very efficient. Invoking PHP uses the CPU. We can help guide you, but you will need significant technical skills to work out what's going on, if you don't have those skills you may be best off seeking professional assistance.